# Backing up Tumblr

Tags: backup, tumblr

What is currently the de-facto way of backing up Tumblr tumblelogs? I have "backstage" access to Backupify's Tumblr service, but (as they forewarned) it's not all too stable.

Answer (score 3):

Here's a very barebones [webapp](http://boutofcontext.com/tumblr_backup.php) that will let you back up your Tumblr page. Was featured on [Lifehacker](http://lifehacker.com/5060476/back-up-your-tumblr-blog).

Answer (score 3):

you can also try this free tool, written in java: http://code.google.com/p/tumblr-backup/

but it just backs up the photos. But an advantage is, that it does incremental backups, starts on each run where it left off the last time.

Comment: Interesting, thanks. Do you know if it also downloads linked high-res versions of the photos?

Answer (score 1):

If you have a Mac, there's a [Mac application](http://staff.tumblr.com/post/286303145/tumblr-backup-mac-beta) available. I know that at one point there was an effort to port this (it's built on PHP scripts, so it shouldn't be too tough) to other platforms, but I guess nothing ever came of that.

Answer (score 1):

You can try using [Tumblelog Backup Jammy](http://boutofcontext.com/tumblr_backup.php), just fetch your posts and save the html. :)