# Download Tumblr favorites

Tags: tumblr, backup

I'd like to backup the favorites of my Tumblr user account. They are publicly accessible (at `tumblr.com/liked/by/<USERNAME>`; can be (de)activated in the Dashboard settings).

There is a [backup webtool](http://boutofcontext.com/tumblr_backup.php) for a Tumblr blog, but it can't be used for favorites (see also [Backing up Tumblr](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/7398/backing-up-tumblr))

In my case, I liked only images. I don't want to backup/download the whole page, but only the image (if possible: in high-resolution, if available).

Is there any way?

Comment: See also on [softwarerecs.se]: [Download my Tumblr likes](http://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/q/3225/60)